# Controller parameters are null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass the value of my inputs to a C# controller, but it always errors out when it tries to use the values because they are null.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('submit', '#form', function () {
            var data = JSON.stringify({
                'val1': $("#val1").val(),
                'val2': $("#val2").val()
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'url',
                contentType: "aplication/json",
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    alert("It works")
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("It failed");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CheckForm(string val1, string val2)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I appreciate any guidance on what step I am missing because as of now I have run out of ideas.

Comment: If the `contentType` in your Ajax POST call just a typo?? It should be `application/json` (with **two** `p` - not just one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use your code, but encountered a lot of problems. The returned result is null like yours. I changed your code and finally got the value. The code result is as follows:

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()

        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string val1, string val2)

        {

             // Do stuff
        }
```

View:

```
<form>
    <input id="val1" />
    <input id="val2" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" id="form2"/>
</form>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    
            var data = {
                'val1': $("#val1").val(),
                'val2': $("#val2").val()
            };
            console.log(data)
          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/test/index',
                //dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: "application/json",
                data:data,
                success: function () {
                    alert("It works")
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    alert("It failed");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create view model

```
public ValViewModel
{
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

Action method:

```
public IActionResult CheckForm([FromBody] ValViewModel viewModel)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```